# remove uneccesary info in array outcome

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

anyone can enlighten why was the outcome not as expected based on the following command?

Expected output:
[1 6] ---> print(a) should return in an array only showing the location of the value

```
a = []

data = ['2007-01-03', '2007-01-04', '2007-01-05', '2007-01-08', '2007-01-09'
        , '2007-01-10', '2007-01-11', '2007-01-12', '2007-01-16']
data1 = ['2007-01-04', '2007-01-11']

data = np.array(data)
data1 = np.array(data1)

for idx, day in enumerate(data1):
    a.append(np.where(day == data))

print(a)
```

Comment: What output *did* you get?

Comment: i got the following output:

[(array([1], dtype=int64),), (array([6], dtype=int64),)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want use your own code, I can say :
you have list of lists, you can try this:

```
a.append(np.where(day == data)[0][0])
```

but you can convert `numpy.array` to `list` and use `index` like below:

```
print([data.tolist().index(day) for day in data1])
```

`numpy` is slow you can see runtime of `list` and `numpy` in below:

```
%timeit ([data.tolist().index(day) for day in data1])
# 3.58 µs ± 123 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit  for day in data1: a.append(np.where(day == data)[0][0])
# 8.47 µs ± 224 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy` for this is a bit of overkill, but the correct output you wish for is done like this:

```
for idx, day in enumerate(data1):
    a.append(np.where(day == data)[0][0])

print(a)
```

That's because `np.where` returns a tuple of indexed results, not just results

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
a = []

data = ['2007-01-03', '2007-01-04', '2007-01-05', '2007-01-08', '2007-01-09'
    , '2007-01-10', '2007-01-11', '2007-01-12', '2007-01-16']
data1 = ['2007-01-04', '2007-01-11']

data = np.array(data)
data1 = np.array(data1)

for idx, day in enumerate(data1):
    a.append(np.where(day == data))

for i in range(len(a)):  # Add this part of the code to get values 
    print(data[(a)[i]])
```